# MVC CodeFirst Calculated Property getting error "ObjectContext instance disposed"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have an ASP.NET MVC Code First site. I have a Model `Teacher`, that has a list of `Student`s, each of which has a calculated property `CompletedTests`.
I'm getting the following error when trying to access the calculated property `CompletedTests` from within a ViewModel that contains the list of `Student`s:

```
An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

Teacher:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students{ get; set; }
}
```

Student:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }

    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

    public int TotalTests
    {
        get
        {
            return Tests.Count;
        }
    }

    public int CompletedTests
    {
        get
        {
            return Tests.Count(p => p.IsCompleted);
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Test> Tests{ get; set; }
}
```

Test:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public int QuestionsTotal
    {
        get
        {
            return Questions.Count;
        }
    }

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get
        {
            return Questions.Count(q => q.Completed) >= QuestionsTotal;
        }
    }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions{ get; set; }
}
```

Question:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TestId { get; set; }

    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

HomeViewModel:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }
    public int StudentCount { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Home controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new HomeViewModel();
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var teacher = context.Teachers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.IdentityId == userId);
        if (teacher != null)
        {
            model.TeacherName = teacher.Name;
            model.Students = teacher.Students.ToList();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml section:

```
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var student in Model.Students)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @student.Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @(student.CompletedTests + "/" + student.TotalTests)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

Could somebody please point out why I'm getting the disposed instance error on the `student.CompletedTests` part?

Comment: Sorry, had it on the wrong class. It is on the `Student`, not the `Test`.

Comment: Added those as well. So it looks like I need some `Include` statements in there? I can add one on the `context.Customers`, but can't add it on the `.Clients` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Include to include Tests entity when loading Student entities to avoid lazy loading:

```
model.Students = teacher.Students.Include(t => t.Tests).ToList();
```

This is called eager loading:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

The error you're getting is because ObjectContext (ApplicationDbContext) is no longer available in your view. It is already disposed inside controller's method.